# Adding Booleans to a list results in a TypeError

Tags: python

I've created a blank list and am attempting to add a boolean to that list. However, I'm getting a few different errors. I'm fairly new to Python so any explanations would be helpful.

What I'm attempting to do is:

```
    new_list=[]
    new_list[0] = True #ERROR: TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

or

```
    new_list=[]
    new_list.append(True) #ERROR: TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'bool'
```

More precisely, I'm attempting to send this through a loop

```
    new_list=[]
    for arg in args:
        if (arg == 'foo' or arg == 'bar'):
            new_list[arg] = True
```

Obviously, the error in the first block is because the list is not accepting the boolean that's being passed. The second is also providing a similar error. However, because this is a blank list, shouldn't this accept any input?

I've attempted to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37524936/7038325) however, it looks like even this may not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Python, you cannot specify the size of a list when you create it. As a result, it throws the error that you see. Why not move the `new_list.append(True)` inside your loop?

Comment: `list.append(True)` didn't raise any error to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new_list = []` creates an empty list. In your first try, you are trying to access `new_list[0]`, but the first place in the list (`[0]`) does not exist, because the list is empty.

When you want to add values to the list you need to use `append`. So your second try is correct, you should use: `new_list.append(True)`, but the first line where you define the empty list is wrong. You used `new_list[]` instead of `new_list = []`.

As for the usage of `new_list[]`, it's a syntax error. If you want to define an empty list you should use `new_list = []` or `new_list = list()`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've fixed the issue with the second try above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track the name of the arg if it is either "bar" or "foo", you could try something like this:

```
    list = []
    for arg in args:
        if arg == 'foo' or arg == 'bar':
            argDic = { arg: True }
            list.append(argDic)

    print(list)
    # [{'foo': True}, {'bar': True}]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am mainly just looking at keeping the boolean portion but if I need to come back to track both, then it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```py
new_list = [] #creates a new list
new_bool_list = [True]*10 # creates a list size 10 of booleans
```

In python you don't have to set the size of the list, you can create an empty list and add onto it.

```py
new_list = []
new_list.append(True)
print(new_list)

--------------
output:
[True]
```

for your loop question it depends on your arguments. `new_list[arg] = True` is generally how you set a value in a dictionary (HashMap in other languages). I think you'd be better off researching those for your intended question.